# "Error: Cannot find module 'react'" when consuming Parcel's React component library in Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, parceljs

**Context:**
I try to create a public react component library and use Parcel API to bundle it. The idea is to have a shared React components library to be consumed by other Next.js projects. And when the external project just wants one component in the library, it can import directly to the component it needs without importing the whole library.
What I want to achieve is to be able to import components from the `reproduce-parcel-issue` React library in the Next.js project:

```
/* Import Button component from "reproduce-parcel-issue/index.js" */
import { Button } from "reproduce-parcel-issue";
// or
/* Import Button component from "reproduce-parcel-issue/components/Button/Button.js" */
import { Button } from "reproduce-parcel-issue/components/Button/Button"
// or
/* Import Button component from "reproduce-parcel-issue/components/Button/Anchor.js" */
import { Anchor } from "reproduce-parcel-issue/components/Button/Anchor"
```

**Issue:**
Parcel is able to bundle the library into multiple modules perfectly. But when I try to consume it in the Next.js project that is generated by the "create-next-app" command, it ran into error `"Cannot find module 'react'"` if I don't `includeModules` `react` in the Parcel options configuration script. And when I `includeModule` `react` in the config, then the error changes to `"You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"`.

**Attempted:**
I created a script `build.ts` that will loop through a list of Parcel config and call to bundle API to generate multiple modules.
In Parcel, I tried to do these in the configuration:

- Adjust the `engines` in the Parcel config to `browsers: ['> 0.5%', 'last 2 versions', 'not dead']`, `node: '>= 12'`, and also `parcel: '>2.5'`
- Adjust the `context` field to `browser`/`node`
- Add `targets` field, but it doesn't seem to work (it can build but Next.js couldn't consume it - alway get an error like `"Can't find module '...'"`), also when I include `react` in `includeModules` field or set `includeModules` to true, it produced the error `"Can't have more than 1 copy of React..."`.
- Remove `targets`, add `main` and `module` to `package.json` (ran to same issue above)
- Adjust `outputFormat` to `esmodule`/`commonjs`.

`package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "reproduce-parcel-issue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Code configuration to reproduce parcel issue",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12"
  },
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
  "author": "Thien Huynh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": false,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/core": "^2.5.0",
    "@parcel/packager-ts": "2.5.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc": "^2.5.0",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "2.5.0",
    "@parcel/types": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.31",
    "@types/react": "17.0.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.13",
    "@types/styled-components": "5.1.24",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-parcel2": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.33.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.12",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.1",
    "parcel": "^2.5.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-hotkeys-hook": "3.4.4",
    "react-is": "17.0.2",
    "react-tooltip": "4.2.21",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3",
    "ttypescript": "^1.5.13",
    "typescript": "4.6.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.41",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.13"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^4.x",
    "react": "^17.x",
    "react-dom": "^17.x",
    "react-hotkeys-hook": "^3.x",
    "react-is": "^17.x",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.x",
    "styled-components": "^5.x"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rm -rf ./dist .parcel-cache && ttsc build.ts --outDir . --module es2022 --sourceMap true && mv build.js build.mjs",
    "build": "node build.mjs && yarn build:dts",
    "postbuild": "yarn build:prep:publish",
    "prebuild:dts": "echo 'building dts'",
    "build:dts": "ttsc --emitDeclarationOnly",
    "posbuild:dts": "echo 'done build dts'",
    "prebuild:prep:publish": "echo 'building for publishing'",
    "build:prep:publish": "ttsc src/setupPackage.ts --sourceMap false && mv dist/setupPackage.js ./dist/setupPackage.mjs && node dist/setupPackage.mjs",
    "postbuild:prep:publish": "echo 'done building for publishing'"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./module/index.js",
      "node": "./module/index.js",
      "module": "./module/index.js",
      "default": "./index.js"
    },
    "./components/*": {
      "import": "./module/components/**/*.js",
      "node": "./module/components/**/*.js",
      "module": "./module/components/**/*.js",
      "default": "./components/**/*.js"
    },
    "./icons/*": {
      "import": "./module/icons/*.js",
      "node": "./module/icons/*.js",
      "module": "./module/icons/*.js",
      "default": "./icons/*.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Current Parcel option configuration:

```
{
    detailedReport: { assetsPerBundle: 20 },
    entries: 'src/index.ts' // or 'src/icons/*.tsx' or 'src/components/**/*.tsx',
    targets: {
      main: {
        distDir: 'dist',
        context: 'browser',
        engines: {
          browsers: ['> 0.5%', 'last 2 versions', 'not dead'],
          parcel: '>2.5',
        },
      },
      module: {
        distDir: 'dist/module',
        context: 'node',
        engines: {
          node: '>= 12',
          parcel: '>2.5',
        },
      },
    },
    defaultTargetOptions: {
      isLibrary: true,
      sourceMaps: false,
      shouldOptimize: false,
      outputFormat: 'esmodule',
      engines: {
        parcel: '>2.5',
      },
    },
    shouldPatchConsole: true,
    shouldAutoInstall: true,
    shouldContentHash: false,
    additionalReporters: [
      {
        packageName: '@parcel/reporter-cli',
        resolveFrom: fileURLToPath(import.meta.url),
      },
    ],
    defaultConfig: '@parcel/config-default',
    mode: 'production',
  }
```

In Next.js project, I tried:

- Adjust `next.config.js`, point `alias` of react to `react` in `node_modules` in `webpack` field, also sometimes it couldn't find `styled-components` even that `styledComponents` is set in `compiler` field. So I think this may be an issue with Parcel bundled script, not from Next.js side.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path');
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      console.log('config', path.resolve(process.cwd() + "/node_modules/react"))
      // don't resolvew 'fs' module on the client to prevent this error on build --> Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
      config.resolve.alias.react = path.resolve(process.cwd() + "/node_modules/react")
    }

    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback.react = path.resolve(process.cwd() + "/node_modules/react")
    }

    return config;
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

**Repositories:**

- [Parcel bundling sample script](https://github.com/Thienhuynh95/reproduce-parcel-issue).

  - `build.ts` in the root folder is a script to bundle modules with Parcel API
  - `setupPackage.ts` in `src/` folder is a script to adjust the content of `package.json` and will be called at the end of the bundling process, it will copy it over to `dist` folder.
- [Next.js project consume bundled Parcel library](https://github.com/Thienhuynh95/next-js-consume-bundled-parcel).

**Step to reproduce:**

- Clone this React project "[Parcel bundling sample script](https://github.com/Thienhuynh95/reproduce-parcel-issue)" and run the command below to generate bundled modules in `dist` folder

```sh
yarn && yarn build
```

- Clone this project "[Next.js project consume bundled Parcel library](https://github.com/Thienhuynh95/next-js-consume-bundled-parcel)" (created with the [`create-next-app`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app)).
- Copy generated `dist` folder from "[Parcel bundling sample script](https://github.com/Thienhuynh95/reproduce-parcel-issue)" project over the Next.js project, run command below in Next.js project's terminal to install local module in project's dependencies `node_modules` and build dev server:

```sh
yarn && yarn dev
```

**Possible solution:**
I don't know if this is the issue with Parcel or Next.js configuration. Maybe either making the right configuration options in the Parcel API to generate the bundled script can be used on the client-side (be able to use shared modules (react, react-dom, styled-components, ...) on the browser) or making Next.js to be able to consume the library directly (like importing the library as if it's an internal code/component in Next.js project) before building pages.

I already spent a week just fixing this build, so I really appreciate any help/suggestion to make this work .

Comment: Hi Thien, were you eventually able to fix this issue? I'm facing a similar one but only during build time in Vercel's service, in my local environment, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. I was using Yarn and workspaces and was disabling hoisting React in an effort to solve what I thought was another issue.

Removing the `nohoist` of React, solved this issue for me.

So, remove the following from the root package.json:

```
   "nohoist": [
      "**/react"
    ]
```